# Source Control and Redesign

Tags: mercurial, refactoring

I'm working on my own open-source project. I've recently released the first workable version but I doubt anyone is using it. I'm the only one working on it. I'm using mercurial and my question is I'm planing a pretty big redesign. Not many stones will remain unturned. How to I tackle this in term of source control? Just continue from current head or create a branch?

How often do I commit? Some classes might disappear (split into 2 or functionality moved elsewhere, interface changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd branch the new version if there were any current users of the code (including yourself) who should stay on that for a while.  Merge it back in when the new version is (by whatever measure) equal or better to the old version.

Another consideration is "if a new user comes to look, would I want them to use the old version I am abandoning or try the version I'm making that'll be in even more flux".  If they should stay on the old version then again branch off for the new one.

More likely though your choices are between

- just continuing work on head ("nobody should ever get encouraged to use the old version") or:
- branch off a "stable" or "release-1" branch ("use this if you want something that's old but feature complete/reasonably functional/...") and then doing the new work on HEAD.

Comment: If I ever wanted to go back to current version, in which option would that be simpler? I assume it doesn't really matter? I'm new to mercurial and this is my first real project (not just a script for personal use). So it might be possible that later on I will like my previous design better.

Comment: I use git and not mercurial, but I'm guessing this would work the same: If you are not sure if the new work is "to keep", then do the new work on a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I don't know `mercurial` (I'm using `git` or `svn`...)

First, since you are the only one committing code on your project, it does not matter that much. It would matter if other people contributed code.

I would create a branch (at least under `git`), and I would also tag the state of your code before the redesign.

Do you intend to maintain the old version (with bug-fixes)? I suppose that not. If you do, you probably have to get two branches, one for the version 1 and another for the re-designed version 2.

Perhaps you want to make a branch of the old version, and continue the master branch with the new one.

Regarding frequency of commits, I always suggest doing it very often (e.g. at least each day you work on it, and probably fot each single major feature or bug fix you introduce.). But each commit should (in principle) stay compilable, and should work somehow (whatever that means for you).

It would be interesting if you did mention your open source project explicitly.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I have no intend to do bug-fixes since I don't assume anyone is using it (have not done any "marketing" and it's a "niche product"). See https://bitbucket.org/kienerj/chemdb/overview. If you are interested I suggest to look at the wiki.